# Swift - Store custom object as NSUserDefault

Tags: swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults

Using this: https://github.com/jonasman/TeslaSwift Class:
[ViewController](https://github.com/jonasman/TeslaSwift/blob/07457028e62d6ee53b254c85ad9dcb721e63343d/Sources/TeslaSwift/Model/Vehicle.swift)

I am trying to store a value `vehicle` in NSUserDefault like this:

```
var vehicle: Vehicle!
UserDefaults.standard.set(vehicle, forKey: "selectedCar")
```

But I get the following error:

`Attempt to insert non-property list object TeslaSwift.Vehicle for key selectedCar' terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

Any ideas on how to store it?

Comment: You could make your object conform to Codable and encode to Data before storing.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the doc of [`UserDefaults`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults):

> The UserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing
> common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Boolean values, and
> URLs. These methods are described in Setting Default Values. 
> A default
> object must be a property list—that is, an instance of (or for
> collections, a combination of instances of) NSData, NSString,
> NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. **If you want to store any
> other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
> instance of NSData.**

The old way (more Objective-C way), is to conforms to `NSCoding`. That's a way to transforming from/to `ClassA` <-> `(NS)Data`.
The "new way", is to use `Codable`, which is more Swift, but has some differences from previous solution (it's more "universal", but could have extra steps needed for more "complexes" stuffs).

Since `Vehicle` is `Codable`, use a `Encoder` (usually, `JSONEncoder`) to encode it into `Data`, and then save it into `UserDefaults`, and a `Decoder` (usually `JSONDecoder`) to retrieve it. But it could be also `PlistEncoder`/`PlistDecoder`.

Comment: I tried doing it like this: `let pieceData = try? NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: vehicle, requiringSecureCoding: false)`, but I get error message: `NSForwarding: warning: object 0x600000ce4540 of class 'TeslaSwift.Vehicle' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector`

Comment: Don't, It's `Codable`, don't use NSKeyedArchiver which is for `NSCoding`, use JSONEncoder !